# select field with disabled not inserting

Tags: php, html, mysql

my select field with a disabled attribute is

```
<select  name="gender" id="gender" disabled="disabled">
   <option value="">Select Gender</option>
   <option value="male">Male</option>
   <option value="female">Female</option>
</select>
```

disabled value not inserting in the database so I wrote

```
<input type="hidden" name="gender" value="<?php echo $_POST['gender']; ?>">
```

while value is there, but still showing error

> Column 'Gender' cannot be null

Comment: Put your insert code in question.

Comment: You can only have one element named `gender`. Use a conditional if it is already set. Your second usage is XSS injectable.

Comment: share your validation code here ?

Comment: `$_POST` contains no item named `gender` because disabled input fields don't appear in the parameter sets of forms.  You'll need code, in php, to cope with the absence of the field.

Comment: so what to write code@O.Jones

Comment: i got the answer  with empty value <input type="hidden" name="gender" value="">

Comment: @O.Jones  how  it would be this is duplicate question..u given duplicate question that is related to text field this is for select field both are different(text fileds accepts readonly but select don't) but anyhow i got solution

Answer (score 0):

You can use `readonly` instead of `disabled` like this:-

```
<select  name="gender" id="gender" readonly>
    <option value="">Select Gender</option>
    <option value="male">Male</option>
    <option value="female">Female</option>
</select>
```

Comment: readonly not working for select field

Comment: Try Radio Button Instead of Select.